# Cursor running wild, then crashes on an Asus G73sw

Tags: cursor

The cursor sometimes goes wild, I get random clicks, the windows are resizing, the cursor disappears. In the worst case, clicks and keyboards are disabled.

I've tried the solution given on doc.ubuntu-fr.org and add tu grub :

`i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset=1` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

But it didn't work

What can I do ?

- Graphic card : Geforce GTX460M.
- Ubuntu : 11.10 (64 bits).
- Laptop Asus G73sw

Interface : Unity (since 11.10) - didn't get this problem with Gnome before.
Complement: when a window is resizing, it gets drag-boxes at every corner, center of sides and center of the window. It looks like my touchpad sends random info, or like a "ghost" touchscreen.

lspci result :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)  
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)  
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)  
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)  
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)  
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)  
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)  
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)  
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)  
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)  
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTX 460M] (rev a1)  
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation GF106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)  
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)  
04:00.0 USB Controller: Fresco Logic FL1000G USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)  
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Edit 01-09-12:
Tried on Ubuntu 2D: the behavior is different: it's like i'm randomly clicking on the workspace switcher icon. In the worst case, it can happen several times in a minute.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit your question to include the graphics card in the laptop, what driver you are using, what interface (unity ?), and what version of Ubuntu. You can check the logs for errors.

Comment: Please edit and add output of `cat /etc/lsb-release` , `uname -a` and `lspci` ?

Comment: Radical but efficient: i've disabled the touchpad using the following command: "xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0", and created a launcher for it. It seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

OP Solved problem :

> Radical but efficient: i've disabled the touchpad using the following command: "xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0", and created a launcher for it. It seems to work.